# How to write this reqular expression ? [Get a section from URL]

Tags: php, regex, url

I have three types of url as below but I just need bold ones. How to get bold ones writing regular expression in php ?

page,**Home**

page,Members.**EditProfile**

page,Members.Seller.**Watchlist**

**Type of a full url:**

http://localhost.example:8090/index.php/page,Members.Inbox

Comment: please elaborate. html/code samples appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about `/.*[,.](.*?)$/`?

Usage Example:

```
$output = preg_match('/.*[,.](.*?)$/', $inputValue, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Comment: that regex is completly redunant

Answer (score 3):

Something along

```
[A-Za-z]+$
```

Here is a live version (although it's tailored for ruby, I find it helpful for regex debugging in general):

- http://rubular.com/r/v32oFOiRdo

Comment: `*` should probably be a `+`, as you're matching all the empty lines as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
$part = preg_split('/[,\.]/',$url);
echo $part[count($part)-1];
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to regular expressions, but I am eager. Here is what I got:

```
\b(?:.+\.|,)+(.+)\b
```

This should capture the bolded words in group 1.

Hope this helps, ell.

Answer (score 1):

Given a list separated by commas, periods, or a mix of both, this will put the last field in the \1 backreference.

```
^.*?(?:(?:\.|,).*)*(?:\.|,)(.*?)$
```

http://rubular.com/r/ewBbSVIeZ6